# How do I get discrete factor levels to be treated as continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, r-factor

I have a data frame with columns initially labeled arbitrarily. Later on, I want to change these levels to numerical values. The following script illustrates the problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

m <- 10
n <- 6

nam <- list(c(),letters[1:n])
var <- as.data.frame(matrix(sort(rnorm(m*n)),m,n,F,nam))
dtf <- data.frame(t=seq(m)*0.1, var)
mdf <- melt(dtf, id=c('t'))

xs <- c(0.25,0.5,1.0,2.0,4.0,8.0)
levels(mdf$variable) <- xs

g <- ggplot(mdf,aes(variable,value,group=variable,colour=t))
g +
    geom_point() +
    #scale_x_continuous() +
    opts()
```

This plot is produced.

[image]

The 'variable' quantities are evenly spaced on the plot, even though numerically this is not true. How can I get the spacing on the x-axis correct?

Comment: also,wellspacedcodeiseasiertoread

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can do this simply by transforming the variable to numeric:

```
mdf$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(mdf$variable))

g <- ggplot(mdf,aes(variable,value,group=variable,colour=t))
g +
    geom_point() +
    #scale_x_continuous() +
    opts()
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert your factor into numeric:

```
mdf$numVariable <- as.numeric(as.character(mdf$variable))

g <- ggplot(mdf,aes(numVariable,value,group=variable,colour=t))
g +
    geom_point() +
    #scale_x_continuous() +
    opts()
```

Or just do the conversion in the call to ggplot:

```
g <- ggplot(mdf,aes(as.numeric(as.character(variable)),value,group=variable,colour=t))
```