# R - getting discrete variable to be treated as continous - more difficulty

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm facing the same issue as on this post - [How do I get discrete factor levels to be treated as continuous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386314/how-do-i-get-discrete-factor-levels-to-be-treated-as-continuous#)

I've tried converting my variable from factor to numeric but it didn't work. The graph is still displayed in a discrete format.

```
require(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
m <- 10
n <- 6

nam <- list(c(),letters[1:n])
var <- as.data.frame(matrix(sort(rnorm(m*n)),m,n,F,nam))
dtf <- data.frame(t=seq(m)*0.1, var)
mdf <- melt(dtf, id=c('t'))

xs <- c(0.25,0.5,1.0,2.0,4.0,8.0)
levels(mdf$variable) <- xs

class(mdf$variable)
mdf$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(mdf$variable))

g <- ggplot(mdf,aes(variable,value,group=variable,colour=t))
g +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous()
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: This plot is produced]

Comment: Your output is not the same plot I see when I copy/paste into R. Maybe restart R and try again? This is what I see: http://imgur.com/a/K812n

Comment: Neither of us used set seed - the difference comes from the rnorm function - we get different distributions

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered what i needed to do - in order to visualize the graph in more a like line fashion i needed to use geom_smooth(se=F) instead of geom_point()